# How to submit a form

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to enter the web site https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and send my data (my code) then I want to get back.

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
import requests

url = "http://duckduckgo.com/html"
payload = {'q':'python'}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

When I tried it, I just get a weird HTML form but not the data I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does some work, try for yourself. Requested html file uses **relative addressing**, so it looks ugly without adding **absolute addressing**.

```
import requests

code = '''
line 1
    line 2
        line 3
'''

payload = {
    'poster': 'Default Poster',
    'syntax': 'python',
    'content': code
    }

url = 'https://paste.ubuntu.com/'
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
text = r.text

# If you want your html file to look the same as original
# then uncomment next line, otherwise it's ugly

# text = text.replace('href="/','href="https://paste.ubuntu.com/')

with open('requests_results.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```